# Magento suddendly messed up design

Tags: magento2, permissions, design

i'm in big trouble. I was working on my Magento theme and suddendly something wrong with up my website.
i'm using bootstrap but it's not loading my version but the one of a plugin i installed.
if i disable the plugin it's loading the useragent css and if i analyze the console i've got this result

[image: console]
 my test developement the theme it's correct. so i think i messed up something with magento installation.

Please help, i can kill myself right now.

THANKS!!!

Comment: i add some information. Webite is http://3.122.31.60/

Comment: MOD: if i see the style-l,css file i don't know why but it's using an Amazon css, not mine. What can the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

There can be several causes for your issue. There can be problems with the plugin. Would you please tell me the name of your plugin. May be, it is not compatible with your current version of Magento. Also, there can be issues in the design package settings.

And yes, try installing Magento. It can fix your issue.

**Update:** I have just seen your latest comment. It seems that you have messed up your CSS and JavaScript files. Please, check whether the permissions and ownership have been set properly or not. Also, check if there is any issue with the .htaccess file. You can try following the instructions mentioned [here](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/259).